# My Background Doing problems How to fix it?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have some CSS code for my masterpage with a background, and it's not displaying how I want it to.

The Background shows up on some but not all pages.

When I zoom in with `CTRL & +` it's showing the background but when I reload the page it's not showing the background.

I am using Google chrome and its doing problems on 3 pages

```
body {
    font-family: VorT3eX Font;
    direction: rtl;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-image:url('Pictures/soccer___________d_1920x1080.jpg');
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "VorT3eX Font";
    src: url("Fonts/aharoniclm-boldoblique-webfont.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "VorT3eX Font2";
    src: url("Fonts/SecularOne-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "VorT3eX Font3";
    src: url("Fonts/migdalfontwin-webfont.ttf");
}
#ContentPage
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font2;
    height:auto;  
    width:951px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1.5px solid black;
    background-color:white;
}
#header {
    margin: auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 951px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position:center;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    background-image:url("Pictures/370483.jpg");
}
nav
{
    overflow:hidden;
}

/*שלב ראשון*/
nav > ul 
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
}

nav ul li
{
   display:block;
   float:right;
   position:relative;

}

nav ul a
{
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    float:right;
    padding:10px 16px;

}   
/*שלב שני*/
nav ul li ul
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:none;
    top:38px;
    position:fixed;
}
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        background-image: url("Pictures/370483.jpg");
    }

nav ul li ul li
{
    float:none;
}
a
{
    color:White;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
#Title
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    font-size:32.5px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:underline;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color:gray;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 0.5px black;
}
#ContentText
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:black;
    font-size:18.5px;
}
```

## My SoccerPage That doing problem with the background, Linked with masterpage with the css that top...

Please help guys...

```css
#Title
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    font-size:32.5px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:underline;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top:7px;
    color:#4682B4;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 0.5px black;
}
#Title1
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:black;
    font-size:21.5px;
}
#Picture1
{
    position:relative;
 left: -100px;
 bottom:-10px;
}
#ContentText1
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:black;
    font-size:15px; 
}
#Title2
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:black;
    font-size:21.5px;
}
#ContentText2
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:black;
    font-size:15px; 
}
#Picture2
{
    position:relative;
 left:-100px;
 bottom:-10px;
}
#Title3
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:black;
    font-size:21.5px;
}
#ContentText3
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:black;
    font-size:15px; 
}
#Picture3
{
     position:relative;
     left:-100px;
     bottom:-15px;
}
#FinishText
{
    font-family:VorT3eX Font;
    color:black;
    font-size:15px; 
}
#FinishPicture
{
       position:absolute;
       margin-top:-100px;
}
```

## 2 MY SoccerPageCss (Having MasterPage)

[image: MyProblem][image: This how it need to looks like]

Comment: Could you please provide more info? Maybe a link to the page or the browser you are using?

Comment: @Alex, can you share your HTML construct too ? Host your code at codepen, jsfiddle...

Comment: Yes i will and i am using google chrome

Comment: Link for the html page: http://localhost:39307/MyWebsite/SoccerPage.aspx

Comment: @Alex "localhost:39307/MyWebsite/SoccerPage.aspx" local link not working to all add a live link

Comment: How can i do it lol

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `background-image` oftion first in your code.

```
body{
  background-image:url('Pictures/soccer___________d_1920x1080.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Still doing the problem with my other html pages